# Checkbox editando un registro

Tags: laravel

Estoy editando un regitro y muestro un checkbox que está o no seleccionado según como esté guardado en la base de dato, y funciona... SI está en `cero (0)` se muestra destildado, si está en `uno (1)` se muestra tildado, pero el problema es al cambiar el valor para guardarlo en la edición, toma los valores `NULL` cuando está destildado y `cero (0)` cuando está tildado.

En mi migración:

```
$table->boolean('view')->default(0);
```

En mi código:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('view', $user->view) }}
```

Cuando lo tildo, se guarda como `cero (0)` y cuando no lo tildo queda `NULL` y me muestra un error, cómo hago para que el valor sea `uno (1)` y `cero (0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Como parte de la implementacion general del checkbox, cuando este no esta chequeado, simplemente el valor no se envía, por ello el `null`.

Para soluicionar esto debes crear un input adicional (hidden) antes del checkbox que actuara como valor no chequeado. En el ejemplo, cero (`0`).

```
{{ Form::hidden('view',0) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('view', $user->view) }}
```

Esto permitirá que cuanco el checkbox `view` no este marcado, se envie el campo hidden `view`=`0` (cuando esta chequeado, el input anterior se ignora)

Como referencia para los mas curiosos, el estandar HTML demarca ciertos controles como "exitosos" (enviables) y excluye ciertos estados de controles para ser enviados. Por ejemplo, el checkbox no-chequeado, los controles marcados como `disabled` y algunos mas.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me resuleve el tema del valor `NULL`, pero como muestro el valor guardao en el campo con `$user->view` al deseleccionar el checkbox se guarda como cero `(0)` y se queda sí, no sé como cambiarlo a uno luego.